# gunicorn randomly getting shutdown signal and not restarting in systemd

Tags: systemd

I'm running gunicorn in production with systemd. I periodically get `[INFO] Handling signal: term` and then `Error while closing socket [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` and then it won't start up again saying `Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)`. This has been driving me nuts because prod goes down. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

I running with with FastAPI and I'm on gunicorn 21.2.0.

And I checked memory, that's not it.